# Bootstrap modal - dont close after submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap template, anyhow I am creating a modal [popup] on my page where the user can submit a form. Although The form works fine but on my PHP code I orignally have that after submitting, it'll show a message either if it worked it would say something like 'Your message has been posted' or if it was an error it would show the error.

But unfortunately once I click 'Post' it posts, but when I click 'Open modal' button again to show the modal popup it shows the message then saying it was submitted, meaning I cant post again without reloading the page.

How would I be able to make it show the message without closing the modal, and also when I close, then open it back up [without reloading] it'll return back to my form instead of having a message.

Thanks.

My code: [Might not be exact as I cut a few un-needed things out]

```
<?php
echo '
         <div style="float:left;margin-top:-51px;margin-left:141px;">   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sml" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Send private message
</button>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Send a message to '.$row["username"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> ';
        if($_POST[add2]){

                                $subject = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
                                $content = $_POST['content'];
                                $date = date("F jS, Y g:i a");
                                $receiver = $row["id"];
                                $sender = $member["id"];

                                if(!$content){
                                    echo 'All fields are required';
                                }else{

                                $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `inbox` (`receiver`, `sender`, `subject`, `content`, `date`, `status`) VALUES ('$receiver', '$sender', '$subject', '$content', '$date', 'unread')");
                                $sql->execute();
                                $q = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                                    if($sql){
                                        echo '<center>Message sent!</center>';
                                    }else{
                                        echo '<strong>Error:</strong> '.mysql_error();
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                echo '
                                <div style="overflow:auto;"><form method="post">


                                        <div style="float:left;width:550px;">Subject<br>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="" size="50" maxlength="40">
                                        <br>Message<br>
                                        <textarea style="height:85px;max-width: 550px;" class="form-control" name="content" placeholder="Enter your message here..." ></textarea></div>





                                <br><hr></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <input type="submit" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-primary" name="add2" value="Post">
        </form>
        </div> '; }

?>
```

Comment: I've thought of possibly using Ajax, but have no idea how I would include it into my form.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+ajax&oq=jquery+ajax&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.4177j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: And you dont think i've searched that before?

Comment: Split your you php an html code to separate files :-/

Comment: @user3219007 well no, because you have made no attempt at all to use AJAX or jQuery and you make no mention of it in your question. So why would I think you had searched for that?

Comment: @JakeN Well sorry. I have just tried ajax, and all of the result codes are in html, and no way I would be able to put my php query in it. Im basicly about to give up. Been researching and researching no find.

Comment: I do not think I have ever seen a bootstrap modal as static part of a PHP-submit page before :)